# Is there any possibility to interact with prototype of global constructor function?

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

As far as I see, JS has some sort of protection from accidential rewriting of global function's prototype.

For example, here it's not a global constructor function. Everything works fine.

```js
function func() { };

function Constructor() {
    this.name = 'Luisa';
    this.surname = 'Li';
    this.age = 48;
};

Constructor.prototype = func;

let obj = new Constructor;
let obj2 = new Constructor;
console.log(obj.__proto__ == func); //true
console.log(obj.__proto__ == func); //true
```

But here I'm trying to work with prototype through global constructor function `Object`. Nothing is working.

```js
function func2() { };
Object.prototype = func2;

let a = {};
console.log(a.__proto__ == func2); //false
```

So, is there some kind of protection in JS from rewriting the global prototype? Cause in some cases JS allows us to work straight with global constructor functions (add global methods, for example).

Comment: "*So, is there some kind of protection in JS from rewriting the global prototype?*" yes.

Comment: If you run this in strict mode, you'll also get an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'prototype' of function 'function Object() { [native code] }'"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you log the property descriptor object of the `Object.prototype` property

```js
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Object, 'prototype'));
```

you will notice that, its:

- Not Writable
- Not Configurable
- Not Enumerable

As `Object.prototype` is not-writable, this means that you cannot overwrite the `Object.prototype` but you can, however, add methods (not recommended) to the object pointed to by the `Object.prototype` property.

In strict mode, assigning to a non-writable property throws an error but in non-strict mode, it fails silently.

---

Note: You should use `Object.setPrototypeOf()` method to set the prototype of an object and use `Object.getPrototypeOf()` method to get it.